# Find a particular solution of $y''+2y=10$ by using inspection.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

By inspection find a particular solution of  $y''+2y=10$.

Write the answer in the form  $a_nx^n+....+a_0$  with the highest degree order.

I'm not quite sure what "by inspection" means in this case. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Hint:  there is a very simple solution.  What are the simplest functions to try?

Comment: The standard method for finding a peculiar solution is to try an ansatz of the same form as the right hand side (if it's a polynomial of degree $n$ try a general polynomial of degree $n$ and see if you can match the coefficients)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solving by inspection simply means you look at the problem, and try to come up with a solution through trial and error, using some logical thinking. In this case, setting $y = 5$ is a solution to the equation.

Comment: I feel like that is too easy.. How would you write 5 in the form above?

Comment: You write $a_0=5$, and that's the end of it. $a_n$ for $n\geq 1 =0$.

Comment: $a_0 = 5$ and $a_1 = ... = a_n = 0$

Comment: Lol now I feel dumb. Thank you for your help!

Comment: One way that often works to find particular solutions is just to see if a constant will work.  It is easy to check because all the derivatives become zero.  If it doesn't work, you haven't invested much effort.

Answer (score 1):

Since the $RHS$ of $y''+2y=10$ is a constant, you try $y=C$ in your equation.

With $y=C$ we get $y'' =0$, thus $2C=10$ which implies $C=5$

So your particular solution by inspection is $y=5$